# API-created vendor invoice in Sage Intacct shows 'Pending' state in API response but 'Submitted' in UI

Tags: request, sage, postman-pre-request-script, purchase-order, intacct

I have created a vendor invoice in Sage Intacct using their API, but I'm experiencing a discrepancy between the state of the invoice in the API response and what is displayed in the Sage Intacct UI.

In the API response, the invoice state is returned as 'Pending'. However, when I view the invoice in the Sage Intacct UI, it shows as 'Submitted'. I expected the state to be consistent between the API and the UI.

I've included the XML code I used to create the vendor invoice through the API below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
  <control>
    <senderid>{{sender_id}}</senderid>
    <password>{{sender_password}}</password>
    <controlid>{{$timestamp}}</controlid>
    <uniqueid>false</uniqueid>
    <dtdversion>3.0</dtdversion>
    <includewhitespace>false</includewhitespace>
  </control>
  <operation>
    <authentication>
      <sessionid>{{temp_session_id}}</sessionid>
    </authentication>
    <content>
      <function controlid="{{$guid}}">
        <create_potransaction>
          <transactiontype>Vendor Invoice</transactiontype>
          <datecreated>
            <year>2013</year>
            <month>6</month>
            <day>19</day>
          </datecreated>
          <vendorid>1001</vendorid>
          <referenceno>12345</referenceno>
          <vendordocno>vendordocno001</vendordocno>
          <shippingmethod></shippingmethod> 
          <returnto>
            <contactname></contactname>
          </returnto>
          <payto>
            <contactname></contactname>
          </payto>
          <basecurr>CAD</basecurr>
          <currency>CAD</currency>
          <exchratetype>Intacct Daily Rate</exchratetype>
          <customfields/>
          <state>Pending</state>
          <potransitems>
            <potransitem>
              <itemid>75300GL</itemid>
              <quantity>2</quantity>
              <unit>Each</unit>
              <price>1</price>
              <locationid>E100</locationid>
            </potransitem>
          </potransitems>
          <subtotals>
            <subtotal>
                <description>Freight 75300GL</description>
                <total>8.73</total>
                <absval>9.22</absval>
            </subtotal>
            <subtotal>
                <description>Tax Amt</description>
                <total>2</total>
                <absval>8.73</absval>
            </subtotal>
        </subtotals>
        
        </create_potransaction>
      </function>
    </content>
  </operation>
</request>
```

I have double-checked the XML data and all the required fields seem to be correctly populated. However, I'm unsure why the state of the invoice is not consistent between the API response and the Sage Intacct UI.

Could someone help me understand why this discrepancy is occurring and how I can ensure that the state is correctly reflected in both the API response and the Sage Intacct UI?

Its showing `submitted` in sage UI, I need to show the state is `pending` Then only I can get the edit option from Sage Intact UI,

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you use Postman to read that record back out? Does it show as submitted or pending? When you submitted via Postman you are using a web services user which may have been granted full admin permissions, whereas you as a user may not have the full permissions. Also, do you have workflow enabled and approvals enabled? That might affect things.